# Temporary .vimrc

Tags: vim, configuration, vimrc

Is there a way to read a `.vimrc` file for only a single ssh session?  That is, when I log in I perform some operation so that vim uses say `/tmp/myvimrc` until I log out?

I do not want to permanently overwrite the current .vimrc, I just need to use a different set of settings for the duration of my login every once in a while.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose you have this other set of settings in `/tmp/myvimrc`.  If my reading of `man vim` is correct you can start vim with this set of settings using the following:

```
$ vim -u /tmp/myvimrc
```

Thus, to make this an option for the rest of the session, I would create a function that sets this as an alias for `vim`.  Thus, in `bash` I would put something like this in my `.bashrc` file:

```
function vimswitch {
    alias vim='vim -u /tmp/myvimrc'
}
```

Then, when I wanted my new vim settings, I would just run:

```
$ vimswitch
```

Note that I wouldn't store myvimrc in `/tmp` since this could easily be cleared out upon reboot.  If you are using a shell other than `bash` this should still be possible, but the syntax could differ slightly.

Comment: nice!  That's what I call going the whole 9 yards.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [VIMINIT environment variable](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#VIMINIT) to override the use of the usual `.vimrc` while keeping other parts of the initialization process. VIMINIT should be set to one or more *ex*-style commands (“colon” commands; use pipe (`|`) to separate multiple commands), not just the path to a different initialization file.

```
VIMINIT='so /tmp/myvimrc'; export VIMINIT

vim whatever # uses /tmp/myvimrc, not ~/.vimrc
```

The main difference from using `-u` is that VIMINIT will still allow the other parts of [initialization process](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#initialization) to be used (e.g. system `vimrc`, `evim.vim` (if applicable), et cetera).

Comment: To automatically setting `VIMINIT` variable while logging via ssh you could use file `~/.ssh/environment`. This file could be used only for setting environment variables, so only entry you should add is: `VIMINIT='so /tmp/myvimrc'`. This file is processed only when in sshd configuration option `PermitUserEnvironment` is set to `yes`, so you should test on your own if it works for you or ask your administrator if it is turn on.

Answer (score 4):

When you log in via ssh, ssh sets variable `$SSH_CONNECTION`. Your `.bashrc` could check for this var and if it is set sets alias that you want:

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]
then
        alias vim='vim -u /tmp/myvimrc'
fi
```